# How do I change the Google Analytics tracking code generated by DotNetNuke?

Tags: google-analytics, dotnetnuke

AFAIK, DotNetNuke websites automatically generate your Google Analytics tracking code.

Recently Google has suggested changing the tracking code you need to use ([to this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad)) if you wish to use new features such as demographics. Any idea how to customise the GA code generated by DotNetNuke?

I've looked into the DNN database and the GA code or UA don't seen to exist there. Also checked the language editor without luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editing SiteAnalytics.config in the website root (httpdocs) seems to be the correct solution.

The GA code in /Config/SiteAnalytics.config doesn't affect what is rendered in the page. As Chris mentions below, this might be what is generated for each new portal.

Comment: I think (haven't looked lately) that you'll find an analytics file for each Portal in portals/#/ that config file you found might just be for NEW portals that get created, FYI

Comment: Thanks Chris. You are right that /Config/SiteAnalytics.config only seems to apply when a new portal is created. I modified this file and didn't affect an existing portal. However the file /Portals/0/GoogleAnalytics.config only contains the Google UA number and not the actual tracking code, and is also the only config file in that directory. I guess I'll keep looking.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the siteanalytics.config file in the root of the website?

Comment: I want to use the new Universal Analytics but there is another property that needs to be replaced like the tracking id (the website name).  Did you find a way of doing that?

Comment: Thanks for your advice Chris, I also tried siteanalytics.config file in the root of the website now. Then cleared the cache and restarted the site but it still seems to be using the old tracking code. It's proving tricky to find.

Comment: Did you resolve this, I am using the new tracking code successfully in DNN 7.

Comment: I haven't resolved it yet. I have changed siteanalytics.config in the website root, and also /Config/SiteAnalytics.config. Neither of them changed what the website is generating. How did you do it J King?

Comment: Changing siteanalytics.config in the root seems to have worked now. Not sure what happened before. Thanks all for the solution. I've modified above to reflect this.

Comment: this is late - you have to restart you application to get the change immediately, under host settings

Comment: @JKing just put a hardcoded 'auto' property where the website name/url would go. The script is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Use page "host->Configuration Manager" to change the  siteAnalitics.config file. Just save and the changings will apply immediately. 
Works for DNN 7.3. Don't know when was added.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that i am using DNN 7

WHat version are you using?

Here is all of what is in my root SiteAnalytics.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AnalyticsEngineConfig>
    <Engines>
        <AnalyticsEngine>
            <EngineType>DotNetNuke.Services.Analytics.GoogleAnalyticsEngine, DotNetNuke</EngineType>
            <ElementId>Head</ElementId>
            <InjectTop>False</InjectTop>
            <ScriptTemplate>
                <![CDATA[     

                <script type="text/javascript">

                      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                      ga('create', '[TRACKING_ID]');
                      ga('send', 'pageview');

                </script>

          ]]>
            </ScriptTemplate>
        </AnalyticsEngine>
    </Engines>
</AnalyticsEngineConfig>
```

Paste that and upload to your ftp.  Make sure the site you are testing has a google tracking ID set in the google analytics setting for the site otherwise this code will not show up.

Comment: Did you use this code and assign a tracking number in the google analytics settings for the portal?  When you viewed your page source in the browser did it have any of the above java code in the html head or nothing?

Comment: I have this exact code running on 6.1.2, view the page source of  http://www.firefighterbtu.net and you will see it is using the new universal analytics code in the html head.  Maybe post the contents of your config file to see if there are any errors in it.

Comment: You can add ,'auto' parameter to the ga() create instance to have it find the domain automatically since DNN doesn't have a way to do it in their current DNN7.0 version implementation. See here for more details: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs

Answer (score 2):

For DNN 9.x:

There are a couple guides out there but they are not fully up-to-date so below I compile more complete steps.

https://blog.bayareasearchengineacademy.org/web-analytics/how-to-install-and-configure-google-tag-manager-in-dotnetnuke-dnn/

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155268/using-google-tag-manager-with-dnn

Both of the above insert the Google Tag Manager script and noscript codes in the body. That's not ideal. Google wants the script tag in the HEAD and the noscript tag in the BODY.

Also they guides don't describe how to update your Tracking_ID which is hidden from DNN Community 9.x installs.  Here is how to do it all.

1. Use the instructions from Google to set up your Account and Container. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en&ref_topic=3441530
2. Using the section "Add, update and publish tags" from the above link setup a new "Tag" and choose "Tag Type" of "Universal Analytics". Under "Google Analytics Settings" dropdown choose "New Variable" and enter the Google Analytics "Tracking ID" for the site you want to track. Give the "Tag" a "Trigger" of "All Pages".
3. Save everything and Name your variable and tag something like "Universal Analytics Variable" and "Universal Analytics Tag".
4. You should now be back at the home page of your Google Tag Manager "Workspace". Look in the top right corner and click the Workspace ID which will be something like "JTF-F9CBJA". Copy the code and note the instructions.
5. Go to your DNN install via FTP and find "SiteAnalytics.config" which is in the root of your website. Edit SiteAnalytics.config so that it resembles the first sample code below. Note that I have created XML to insert the "script" tag at the top of the HEAD and the "noscript" tag in the BODY.
6. Now go to the root of your DNN portal. The default root is at "/portals/0". If you have multiple portals you'll need to follow these instructions for each portal.
7. Find the file GoogleAnalytics.config. Find the node for "SettingName" with the value "TrackingId". Change the "SettingValue" below it to your Google Tag Assistant "Workspace ID" (from the code you saved above). If you don't have those nodes in your GoogleAnalytics.config then copy from my second code sample below. Save the file.
8. Reload the website that you updated. Check the source to see if the "script" code is inserted in the HEAD and the "noscript" code in the BODY.
9. If you're using Chrome install the "Tag Assistant" extension from the store and use it to verify that the code on your page is working.
10. Note by default DNN does not insert the GA code for administrators unless you check the box "Track for Administrators".  Personally I check that box so that my Tag Manager shows the code properly.  Google Analytics filters out known administrators by default so I don't feel it's safe.

Code Sample 1 - SiteAnalytics.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AnalyticsEngineConfig>
<Engines>
    <AnalyticsEngine>
        <EngineType>DotNetNuke.Services.Analytics.GoogleAnalyticsEngine, DotNetNuke</EngineType>
        <ElementId>Head</ElementId>
        <InjectTop>True</InjectTop>
        <ScriptTemplate>
            <![CDATA[     

                <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
                <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','[TRACKING_ID]');</script>
                <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->        

            ]]>
        </ScriptTemplate>
    </AnalyticsEngine>
    <AnalyticsEngine>
        <EngineType>DotNetNuke.Services.Analytics.GoogleAnalyticsEngine, DotNetNuke</EngineType>
        <ElementId>Body</ElementId>
        <InjectTop>False</InjectTop>
        <ScriptTemplate>
            <![CDATA[     

                <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
                <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=[TRACKING_ID]"
                height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
                <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->     

            ]]>
        </ScriptTemplate>
    </AnalyticsEngine>
</Engines>
</AnalyticsEngineConfig>
```

Code Sample 2 - GoogleAnalytics.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyticsConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Settings>
    <AnalyticsSetting>
      <SettingName>TrackingId</SettingName>
      <SettingValue>ENTER YOUR WORKSPACE ID HERE</SettingValue>
    </AnalyticsSetting>
    <AnalyticsSetting>
      <SettingName>UrlParameter</SettingName>
      <SettingValue />
    </AnalyticsSetting>
  </Settings>
</AnalyticsConfig>
```

*Finally: This all requires some serious technical work so use these instructions at your own risk.

Comment: Updated the noscript tag XML so that it does not insert at the top of the body because this caused a conflict on one of my sites.